# Dynamically setting ellipsis and maxlines of textView doesn't working properly in recyclerview item

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to set maxlines of textview dynamically in some case as 3, or Int.MAX_VALUE(intent to ellipsize automatically when fit view height) in recyclerview.

In result, maxlines set properly but textview doesn't make ellipsis.

For example, I set maxlines as 3 dynamically (ellipsis property is set up as "end" at xml file) and set text "text\ntext\ntext\ntext"

My intention:

> text  
>   text 
>    text...

Actual Result:

> text  
>   text 
>    text

I tried to set ellipsis property dynamically too, but it still doesn't work.

What should I do to work as I intended?

Answer (score 0):

firstly intialize your TextView

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text);
```

then,you can dynamically set Max lines by passing your Dynamic data to X:

```
t.setMaxLines(X);
```

Comment: I'm already trying to set maxlines dynamically. The problem is textview doesn't ellipsize properly even though I set maxlines and ellipsis property as Truncated.END.